# javascript document.getElementById only reading first value from php mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Let me try and say this in a way that doesnt get anyone angry or confused.

I have a value that I am outputting into a table.

The value is populated by mysql and php.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<table>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td id='countryDbId'>".$row['country']."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "</table>";
                        }
                        $conn->close();
                    }
                    ?>
```

Then I try to read all the values that were output with javascript.

```
                  <script>
                    var country = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML;
                    console.log(country);
                    </script>
```

The output is only the first value even though there are over 100 values in that column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `id='countryDbId'` in a `while` loop? ... Nope, no. Dont do that.

Comment: A better solution would be to `json_encode` all the values into a string that you echo into either a `data-attr` or dynamically into your `script` block as a `var` define. That way you wouldn't need to fiddle with CSS id's or classes for this.

Comment: IDs in HTML have to be unique. The way you are doing it only 1 can be/will be "seen".

Comment: You need to get a list of the country names in javascript?